# Risks of Authenticated Users group assigned by default

Tags: windows, access-control-list

I have noticed that Windows seems to give all `Authenticated Users` powerful rights (Modify) propagated from the root of the drive. Suppose you create a folder under the root and do not adjust its permissions. What are the ramifications of leaving the `Authenticated Users` access? If end users who do not understand Windows security features create folders directly under the root on their drives without adjusting this, what are the risks? What are the best practices in this area?

Comment: If you don not alter the permissions to the necessary ones, it's *your* fault. As administrator, you are expected to assign the kind of permissions that allow only the operations you intend to be allowed.

Comment: Ummm, I mentioned end users doing stuff outside of sysadmins control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For local machines, the one on their desk, this is actually not that bad. They're usually a local deity anyway. The big exception to this is shared-usage workstations, where you have multiple people sharing the same station (such as a receptionist's-desk, with a rotation of people actually sitting there). That may have some problems.

As for Server, it's much less of an issue in very large part because of the share permissions set for getting to the file-system. Microsoft has long had guidelines published saying that you don't grant Authenticated-User anything meaningful as a *share permission* and instead use an actual security group. If you set a security group to have (M) to a share, the file-rights will be gained from AuthUser, but authenticated users outside of the security group won't have access.

It's best to set permissions in tandem, but having liberal permissions on the file-system and clamping down at the share level is a valid, if not that great, idea.

Comment: Thanks! I definitely believe you. A link to the "long had guidelines" documentation would be awesome to share with other people I deal with.

Comment: @binarycoder Here [is one for you.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780313%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)